# Need an OpenID provider meeting certain criteria for identifying on SX sites

Tags: support, login, openid

(Not really sure this question belongs here. But I'll give it a shot anyway.)

I used to use `myopenid.com` for identifying on the SX network, and liked it. Now that it's gone, I'm using another provider (never mind which exactly), but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I need a provider which is:

- Free to use
- Is non-commercial, or at least, has a relatively harmless business model (e.g. showing you ads on the landing page or something silly like that).
- Is stable and available.
- Can be expected to exist for a few years forward.
- Has a relatively 'upstanding' image.
- Is highly unlikely to be sending all logs to the NSA, and more generally not evil (so, not Google or Yahoo or any of those).
- Is not part of some social network website.

The last criterion is a must, since I'm connecting from behind a corporate firewall which is likely to block sites like my current provider; and so is the next-to-last criterion, for moral/political reasons.

Comment: Like many people, I've simply gone for the StackExchange server for this. Running an OpenID back-end is not a simple operation so you'll do well to find one run for free that's not got some finance model. (Any company might have to send logs to the NSA if the servers are in the US: this sort of thing is not optional.)

Comment: @JosephWright:  <surprise> There's an SX OpenID server? </surprise>

Comment: https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry for using you as tech support, but after creating an account there, and using https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid as the URL, I get: "Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/7170bb20-b0e0-4516-892a-d41401df0a95) is not owned by the logged in user." Is there some association I need to make?

Comment: Probably one for the main meta site. Did you try just choosing the StackExchange option from 'add more logins'?

Comment: @JosephWright: Just tried that, and got the same error message when reaching the openid provider. I'm trying all this for the login into stackoverflow.com (not the meta site).

Comment: Perhaps http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136917/unable-to-link-openid-on-stack-overflow-with-sourceforge?

Comment: @einpoklum try using just `http://openid.stackexchange.com` as the URL, without the `/openid` on the end. If you still have trouble, e-mail `team@stackexchange.com` and let us know what's going on. The exact wording of any error messages you're seeing would be particularly helpful. Screenshots, too.

Comment: @Pops: It worked, thanks. But it was quite a challenge to get to the point of it working... perhaps you should consider placing a play-by-play guide to using the SX OpenID server somewhere noticeable (e.g. under the textbox for entering an OpenID URL)?